# Error importing GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a problem trying to import `GeoPandas`. Since it was impossible to install the package in the normal channels within *Anaconda*, because of possible incompatibility with other spatial packages, I create a new channel called `geo_env`as it was sugested in other chats, as follows:

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install python=3 geopandas
```

by this way it was possible to install successfully `Geopandas`, however, now I have a mixing of environments and by importing `geopandas as pdg` I get:

```
import geopandas as gpd
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-a62d01c1d62e>", line 1, in <module>
    import geopandas as gpd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
```

and even if I apply

> python -c "import geopandas; print(geopandas.**version**)"

Now, I feel that I see the end of the path!! I have not idea now how to make this work, and I really need `Geopandas` installed for some spatial analysis. Important to be mentioned, that I also have installed `shapely` and `fiona`. Both of these are sometimes recommended to have installed before `Geopandas`.

Comment: Just install your required packages at the same time you install geopandas and let conda figure it out, i.e `conda install python=3 geopandas shapely fiona some_package something_else another yet_another`.  Don't try and mix your envs, just create a new one and use that.

Comment: You are likely trying to import geopandas in different env than `geo_dev`. Make sure you are using the correct environment.

Comment: Thanks, the problem now as I see is that the environment `geo_env` does not have `spyder` installed: `channel url: https://conda.anaconda.org/geo_env
error code: 404`. However, some how it is no possible to do it. I do not know yet the reason. This after that I have already activated `geo_env`.

Comment: To solve the problem, I eliminated unnecessary channels, I set the _defaults_ as the highest priority, after that the process looks better.